# Can I rethrow angular http interceptor for 500?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have an http interceptor that will intercept 500 errors and display a dialog box to the user. Below is a snippet of my interceptor code:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    ....
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
        // intercept the respons error

        this.handleAuthError(error, request); // pass error to function
        return of(error.error);
    }) as any, finalize(() => {
        ++this.counter;
        this.enableSubmissionButton(this.counter);
    }));
}

private handleAuthError(err: HttpErrorResponse, request: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // handle your auth error or rethrow
    let errorMessage: any = '';

    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        errorMessage = `Error: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
        errorMessage = `Error Code: ${err.status}\nMessage: ${err.message}`;
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
            this.userAuthService.purgeAuth();
        } else if (err.status === 500 || err.status === 404) {
            this.dialog.open(MessageDialogComponent, {
                disableClose: true,
                data: err.error.Message || `${err.status} ${err.statusText}`,
            });
        }
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
}
```

I'm making some changes in one of my API calls in a component and I now want to know if there is any kind of http error when calling the API.

```
this.subscription.add(
        url.subscribe(data => {
            if (data.Status) {
                // Save was successful.
            } 
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    );
```

Obviously the above console.log will not happen as the http interceptor will take care of it.
What can I do to check if there was (for example) a 500 error on my request above, even though the http interceptor has handled it. I need to run some specific code if there are any such errors on this request